# Show app icon from other app

Tags: android, flutter, android-drawable

I want to show the app icon from a packageName different than the current one in my flutter app. The platform-channels can't transport drawable / bitmaps. What will be the bast practice for such a task? (It's an Android only feature)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Bitmap.compress (Bitmap.CompressFormat format, 
            int quality, 
            OutputStream stream)
```

to a ByteArrayOutputStream to obtain a byte array in PNG format, which can cross platform-channels, then at the Flutter end turn the resulting `List<int>` back. (Check whether the `List<int>` is already a `Uint8List`, otherwise convert it.)

There are two types of `Image` in flutter depending on your use case. The normal one is a Widget - create it with `Image.memory`. The other form (`ui.Image`) is akin to a bitmap, if you want to draw the resulting image on a Canvas.

```
Future<Codec> instantiateImageCodec (
  Uint8List list
)
```